# Loading point features into Network Analyst without losing the point's attribute fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, network-analyst, closest-facility

I have points that represent schools (facilities) and points that represent homes (incidents). I need to do a [closest facility analysis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/closest-facility.htm) to calcualte how long the residents need to reach the schools. However, in order to calculate an average traveltime per block of houses, I need the traveltime to be linked to the homes and not to the routes.

The problem: ArcGIS deletes every attribute field of the point layers (including the ID Field), when loading them into the [Network Analyst](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/what-is-network-analyst-.htm). That makes linking the traveltime from the routes onto the homes very tedious (e.g. via joining the routes to the incidents using their ID and then spatially joining the incidents with the homes).

Is there a way to keep the attribute fields of the original point layer when loading them into the network analyst?

The same problem appears when loading points into a [service layer analysis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm).